# How do you get output from all children in recursive function?

Tags: octave

I am trying to write a script to find all paths from source to sink in your typical max flow problem. This overall will serve as step 1 in an implementation of the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm as a project for class.

I've done some basic debugging, but what seems to be happening is that the algorithm isn't producing all the children it should be via the for loop, and instead just finds the same path a few times then terminates.

```
#pathfinder
function final=pathFinder(A,path) #call with path=1 to initiate
    #A is a matrix that looks like
    # u v w where uv is an edge, and w is its weight (weight is used later)
    vert=path(numel(path)); #get last vertex used
    F=find(A(:,1)'==vert); #find incident edges
    disp("F is");
    disp(F); #displaying these for debugging purposes
    if(sum(F)==0) #terminates with no more edges (happens only at sink)
      #save externally
      disp("path found!");
      disp(path);
      final=0; #terminate it
    else
     for i=1:numel(F) #this should split this up in "children" for recursion, but it does not. Why?
        b=F(i);
        path=[path, A(b,2)]; #add new vertex/edge to path
        disp("non-final path");
        disp(path);
        disp("going deeper");
        final=pathFinder(A,path); #recurs on next vertex
     endfor
    endif
endfunction
```

The example graph I'm using is

```
A=[1 2 0; 1 3 0; 2 3 0; 2 4 0; 3 4 0];
```

which should have paths [1 2 3 4], [1 2 4], [1 3 4] (in this order from the algorithm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

1. `vert=path(numel(path))` says that the number of elements along the path is the vertex index you want to start from. This is wrong. You need to use `vert=path(end)`, the last element in the path.
2. Within the loop, you update `path`. The next loop iteration, you are therefore using the modified `path`, and not backtracking. You need to modify the `path` input to next recursive call, but not the local `path` variable.

This is the corrected code:

```matlab
function pathFinder(A,path) % call with path=1 to initiate
   % A is a matrix that looks like
   %  u v w where uv is an edge, and w is its weight (weight is used later)
   vert=path(end); % get last vertex used
   F=find(A(:,1)'==vert); % find incident edges
   if isempty(F) % terminates with no more edges (happens only at sink)
      % save externally
      disp(path);
   else
      for b=F % loop over the incident edges
         pathFinder(A,[path, A(b,2)]); % recurse on next vertex
      end
   end
end
```

<sup>I have removed the debugging output for brevity. I've also changed some Octave-only things (`endfor`, `#` comments) to something that will also run in MATLAB.</sup>